# How can I create SQLAlchemy tables within __init__.py?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am working on an application to which I'd like to add a User model. Traditionally the application is started via `python3 runserver.py`, but I needed a mechanism for creating admins, so I added this function:

```
def create_admin():
    username = input("Please enter username: ")
    # "select * from user where user.username = username;"
    q = db.session.query(User).filter(User.username == username)
    # if that user exists, don't create it
    if db.session.query(q.exists()).scalar():
        print("User already exists. Exiting.", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
    # otherwise, create it and commit to db
    password = getpass.getpass("Please enter password (it will not be echoed): ")
    admin = User(username, password=password, admin=True)
    db.session.add(admin)
    db.session.commit()
```

This will be imported from the project `foo`, whose `__init__.py` looks something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
import tempfile
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
sqllite_uri = os.path.join('sqlite:///{}'.format(tempfile.gettempdir()), 'test.db')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = sqllite_uri
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

socketio = SocketIO(app)

from foo.models import create_admin
from foo import views, models
```

The problem is that the tables are created within `runserver.py` as a part of the `__main__`, so when I call `create_admin` from the command-line, the tables don't exist.

I put the `db.create_all()` as the first line in `create_admin()` which worked, but it would fail if I needed to create multiple admins. This tells me **there's nothing wrong with the User model**. Further, this leads me to think that it would be better to create the tables when `foo` is imported for the first time.

I tried adding `db.create_all()` directly after the `db` object was created within `__init__.py`, but I was still getting exceptions from my `create_admin` call because my User table doesn't exist. `db.create_all()` doesn't know about the tables at this point, which makes me think I need to import the models.

Is there a way to create the tables in `__init__.py` that I'm overlooking? Perhaps the tables in `foo.model` aren't being seen at the time that `db` is created, but I couldn't figure out how to import the models in `__init__.py`.

---

## EDIT: I have a workaround, but I don't like it:

1. `python3 runsersever.py` to create the tables
2. ^C to exit
3. Create admin...
4. Restart server.
5. ???
6. Profit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## My current solution:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
import tempfile
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
sqllite_uri = os.path.join('sqlite:///{}'.format(tempfile.gettempdir()), 'test.db')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = sqllite_uri
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

socketio = SocketIO(app)

from foo.models import create_admin
from foo import views, models

db.create_all()
```

## The explanation:

By the time we are ready to create the tables (i.e., by calling `db.create_all()`), all the tables are known because the models have been imported from `foo`.

This might not be the idiomatic way of doing this, but I'm posting it for future users. I'm still open to better options!

Comment: Why do you feel this is not idiomatic? If you want `db.create_all()` to be execute after the model definitions, then the most logical place to put it would be after you import the model definitions. Where do you want `db.create_all()` to be instead?

Comment: @univerio I'm relatively new to python. I didn't say it was not idiomatic, I was just issuing a caveat in case it was. Either way, idiomatic != logical.